# Active Record Association with models/controllers of Host and Tours

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Been trying multiple methods to implement the association of tours to a unique host.

Host (user)has been setup using devise by using email and password only, when later on will add further profile data fields.

Created all the relevant basic setups for the tours (title and text fields only) but just want to get the association working before moving the Tour layouts further.

The tours can only be created once the host has signed in which is currently working.

Note: there are # for comments on lines of code as I was trying to see if these work but with no success.

Below are my working structure:

**host.rb**

```
class Host < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  #before_save { |host| host.fullname }

  validates :email, presence: true #length: {maximum: 50}

  has_many :tours, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**tour.rb**

```
class Tour < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :host
    #validates :host_id, presence: true
    validates :title, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5 }
end
```

**migrate: devise_create_hosts.rb**

```
class DeviseCreateHosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:hosts) do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      # t.string   :confirmation_token
      # t.datetime :confirmed_at
      # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at


      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :hosts, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :hosts, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    # add_index :hosts, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
    # add_index :hosts, :unlock_token,         unique: true
  end
end
```

**migrate: create_tours.rb**

```
class CreateTours < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :tours do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :text
      t.references :host, index: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_foreign_key :tours, :hosts
    add_index :tours, [:host_id, :created_at]
  end
end
```

So the basics of it is I want to add the tours to the host and also update the layouts html.

**Hosts - show.html.erb** - this needs to add some lines for the tours that are related.
So under hosts/1 I need the basics to show the tours output for title and text fields.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="center">

    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Verification</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            Email Address<br>
            Phone Number here andmpre
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-9">
        <h2><%= @host.email  %></h2>

    </div>
</div>
```

Tours - index.html.erb
- like to add line of code for to show the host id

```
<h1>Index TOURS</h1>

<%= link_to 'New Tour', new_tour_path %>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Text</th>
  </tr>

  <% @tours.each do |tour| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= tour.title %></td>
      <td><%= tour.text %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', tour_path(tour) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_tour_path(tour) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', tour_path(tour),
              method: :delete,
              data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

hope there is a quick way that someone can help me with.
tried tutorials but as I am a newbee to ROR sometimes they confuse when I am trying to keep it simple.

Comment: what you want man?

Comment: So when a host logins, they can create tours unique to their host.id. And under the show.html I want to got to hosts/1 and see all the tours related to that host

Comment: what error are you facing while achieving this?

Comment: not really facing an error.. havent been able to show the tours under the specific host. as i am new been trying few methods with no success so made a clean version and see if i could get help here.  
maybe its a big ask for this but just need the basic start of code that puts the tours related to that host.

Comment: you can create show_tours method in controller and make routes with parameter which will take host id in url and in method use `@tours = host.find(params[:id]).tours` and use `@tours` in view

Comment: yes .. but havent got it to work yet.. you able to make code snippets for it?

Comment: do you have git repo?

Comment: I can add it to the git repo tomorrow.  Away from the desk now